# Confusion with tag [Cyprus]

Tags: discussion, tags

[cyprus](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyprus) seems ambiguous as it's not clear if it refers to the [Republic of Cyprus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus) (a country that's a member of the European Union) or [Northern Cyprus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Cyprus) a state that consists of the northern part of Cyprus which is only recognised by Turkey. The tag is already used for both.

The tag description is not clear either:

> Questions relating to the government or politics of Cyprus

Should these two states have different tags? If so, please add an answer to suggest how to proceed. If not (questions relating to either can use the existing tag), please clarify in an answer as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cyprus is a common name for the Republic of Cyprus. See, for example, the [relevant article](https://europa.eu/european-union/about-eu/countries/member-countries/cyprus_en) on the site of the European Union, or on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus). Northern Cyprus is almost never formally referred to as Cyprus by anyone, with the possible exception of its own citizens.

I've added the [northern-cyprus](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/northern-cyprus) tag to a couple of questions that explicitly mention Northern Cyprus. Feel free to add it to others. I've also updated both tags info to avoid any further confusion.

I also propose we create a [republic-of-cyprus](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republic-of-cyprus) synonym for [cyprus](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyprus). This, however, isn't easily reversible by the community, so I'd like to wait a while to see if anyone objects before going through with it.

Comment: Shouldn't [republic-of-cyprus] then be the main tag? Similar to [republic-of-ireland]? Or would the tag excerpts suffice in this case?

Comment: I don't see why the tag info wouldn't suffice @JJJ. However, I think I should point out that I'm Greek and my opinions on the matter are probably a lot more biased than I care to admit. So, it's probably best if I remove myself from the discussion at this point and let others decide on the synonyms.

Comment: Probably best to just rename [tag:cyprus] to [tag:republic-of-cyprus] so people have to explicitly choose. I did the same thing with [tag:ireland] -> [tag:republic-of-ireland]/[tag:northern-ireland] last year, and seems to work well (ireland tag hasn't been re-created since, and all questions I've seen since were tagged correctly).

Comment: @yannis Should we file a formal request to create the tag now that it's been a few weeks or can you do it straight away?

Comment: I'm not sure that would work for our current crop of [tag:cyprus] questions @MartinTournoij. For example, we have [one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/3204/101) that is about the island as a whole.  And it happens to be among the more popular questions on the site.

Comment: @yannis We should just replace the tag on that question with both [tag:republic-of-cyprus] and [tag:northern-cyprus]. There's no need to have a third tag specifically to refer to the island's landmass